# Angular: Number field validation using directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to validate a input:number field using directive. The purpose of the field is to accept only numbers between 0-9 or a decimal number up to 3 decimal places (numbers will be positive all time without any symbols).

As there are same type of fields of more than 30 so thought of creating a directive that will prevent users from entering unnecessary characters.

Below is my code for the same along with a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/number-test-directive?) sample:

Directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validTestValue]'
})
export class NumberDirective {

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e) {
    const key = ['Backspace', 'Delete', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.'];
    let check = key.includes(e.key) && /^\d{1,7}((.)|(.\d{0,3})?)$/.test(e.target.value);
    console.log(check)
    if (!check) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" validTestValue class="testInput-field text-center" />
<!--Same input fields are there many times in my code-->
```

The problem with this code is that I can enter value as I desired i.e. only digits and the decimal point is accepted but few other issues are arising like below:

1. Excepted result should be max 7 digits whether or not it is a decimal number. Example: 1, 12, 1234567
2. If decimal number then max 7 digits before decimal and max 3 digits after decimal. Example: 1, 1.2, 1.12, 1.123
3. Cannot Backspace (if length reached) or move cursor.
4. If the field is blank without any default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Dilshan's solution it will only check number of digits after decimal and also it's not validating spaces as per his regex.
I am updating Dilshan's solution a bit to meet your requirement as per my understanding.

REGEX: `^([\d]{0,7})((\.{1})([\d]{1,3})?)?$`

HTML: `<input type="text" validateNumber="7.3" />`

This is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rybkvv?file=src/app/validate-number.directive.ts) solution for your reference.

Hope this helps you .

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your regx

> /^\d{1,7}((.)|(.\d{0,3})?)

this allows 1 to 7 digits ( {1,7} matches the previous token between 1 and 7 times, as many times as possible )

This is what I'm using currently. It can control how many decimal points allowed in a field

[numbers only directive](https://gist.github.com/djay1988/4bedd077fdf7c7a08fc16d74de5bcd06)

In template file

```
<input type="text" numbers-only="2"  placeholder=""
```

Comment: the solution is a working charm for the decimal part but how could I restrict the user to enter a maximum of 7 digits before the decimal part? At this moment what am seeing is that it's only validating after the decimal part and also accepting "Space" which I don't want.